# Video contest script

Tags: wordpress, video, joomla, voting

I am trying to create a website that will hold video contests.

1) Users will submit their own videos - either upload or Youtube.
2) Visitors will vote on their favorite video and highest voter will win.
3) I would love it if each vote required a name to be entered and maybe require them to login using their Facebook account to associate each vote and allow people to connect.

There will be different categories and different contests running at the same time.

I really just need something that will allow people to submit their own video from Youtube and then for people to vote on their favorite.  I want contest info to be displayed and a time window to exist.  Maybe allow people to upload video for 1 week, then voting starts after that.

Is there anything like this for Wordpress or is there any other script or combination that does the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

You have two options to accomplish what you'd like in Wordpress -

**1. Themes:** You can utilize a content-sharing theme, typically available as a premium theme ($$), that includes functions such as user-submitted posts and voting/liking other users posts. Certain themes may require some code edits to be custom tailored for a video-centered website.

Here are a few themes that will achieve your goal:

[I Love It! Content Sharing Theme - ThemeForest](http://themeforest.net/item/i-love-it-content-sharing-wordpress-theme/698475)

[Me Gusta - ThemeForest](http://themeforest.net/item/me-gusta-userdriven-content-sharing-theme/570785)

**2. BuddyPress:** Considered the epitome of content sharing and social networking, BuddyPress is a plugin available for your Wordpress website and installs very easily. This will most likely require the most editing, but the plugin itself is free. Take a peek at BuddyPress' features on the latest Wordpress Twenty Twelve theme [here](http://testbp.org).

Comment: Thanks!  I think the Theme route will be the best, but I still haven't found the right theme.  Thanks for sharing those two premium themes.  The biggest issue I'm seeing is the lack of a simple video upload option and a voting system for it. The two above allow you to post content but it's a little too much.  It also doesn't have a simple voting thing.